# NetBeans locate a file under app's root folder

Tags: angularjs, netbeans, file-location

In my project called `App`, I have a controller, which contains a complex object that has a field referencing `App/img/blue.jpg`:

```
myApp.controller("myController",function($scope){
   $scope.message = "Home Page"; 
   $scope.Photo1 = {
       name: "blue_bird",
       image:"/img/blue.jpg"
   };
});
```

However the image is not loading when I do this:

```
 <img src="{{Photo1.image}}" />
```

I also tried changing the `image` field to `img/blue.jpg` and `~/img/blue.jpg`, none works. When I change `image` to a web link, though, it works

Comment: first : use `ng-src` ; second : try with `./img/blue.jpg` in $scope.Photo1 image property

Comment: `./img/blue.jpg` does not work, neither does `./img/blue.jpg/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. In the Projects panel on the left hand side of the window, click the Files tab, drag the file into the editing area, right between the quotation marks of the `src=""` attribute. The `img` tag then looks like this:

```
<img src="../img/blue.jpg" alt="" />
```

So the object in the controller should look like:

```
$scope.Photo1 = {
       name: "blue_bird",
       image:"../img/blue.jpg"
   };
```

And in View:

```
<img ng-src="{{Photo1.image}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Read the documentation here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work
>   right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text
>   {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The
>   ngSrc directive solves this problem.

The buggy way to write it:

```
<img src="{{Photo1.image}}"/>
```

The correct way to write it:

```
<img ng-src="{{Photo1.image}}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your tip but `Photo1.image` still cannot locate the image

Comment: @Dylan just from debug point of view, please hardcode your url to `<img src="/img/blue.jpg" />`. Is the image showing now?